# WebClient DownloadString WITHOUT downloading C#

Tags: c#, post, webclient

I have this chunk of code:

```
using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.QueryString.Add("par1", "1");
    client.QueryString.Add("par2", "2");
    client.QueryString.Add("par3", "3");
    var temp = client.DownloadString("http://www.myurl/example.aspx");
}
```

This does almost exactly what i want: i want to call a page passing parameters. That's all. The page will write those parameters into a db, etcetera...

The problem is that `DownloadString` is ALSO downloading the whole webpage in addiction, and i simply don't need that. I don't need any answer from the page, actually.

How can i do that? I already tought about the obvious solution of discarding the obtained string, but i wonder is there is a smarter way to call a page WITHOUT an answer, passing parameters.

Note: IF you suggest different ways, also write down  how to READ the parameters from the **aspx.cs** page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Implement `client.QueryString.Add("return_page_body", "false");` ?

Comment: I would suggest that you should be looking at making a Web API for this, instead of using one URL for two purposes. If you *really* want to stick with this, what's *wrong* with downloading the content of the page, and then ignoring it? What problem is that creating for you?

Comment: If you don't need a response, why is this a GET? If you don't care about the response, it is presumably *doing* something, in which case it should be a POST, yes? But: does the server support HEAD requests? You could do a HEAD instead of a GET, maybe. Alternatively, you could drop down to http web request/response and just *not read the response stream*. Probably easier to just discard the string, though...

Comment: @JonSkeet no problem, i JUST WONDER is there is a smarter way to call a page WITHOUT an answer, passing parameters.

Comment: @AlexK. your suggestion seems the right way. But what should i write to make sure the page response does not contain all the body?